Создание окна приложения MAUI/WPF для Blazor
Вопрос общий, не по конкретной проблеме, скорей куда идти что бы получить определенный результат.
Хочу создать окно приложения где элемент blazor будет выступать в роли Titlebar, или кастомизировать родной titlebar windows, так, что бы остались возможности родного titlebar, мне нравится wpf там с кастомизацией нету проблем, но есть проблемы с функциональностью, что бы вызвать тот же DragMove(), нужно проверить нажатие левой кнопки мыши, как это обойти я не знаю.
В MAUI проблемы с кастомизацией (по крайней мере у меня), удалось убрать родной titlebar и сделать перемещение окна по нажатию на элемент blazor, но само окно ведет себя странно на разных версиях windows, подскажите как добиться результат, допустим как у VS Code

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Вы делаете совершенно что-то не то... Допустим, WPF, зачем вам DragMove, если там достаточно вернуть "хром"? Ну а если вы хотите просто изменить стандартный заголовок окна в WPF, то опять, это делается иначе. MAUI и др., там тоже есть свои инструменты кастомизации. В любом случае, не существует универсального решения. Выберите что-то одно и уже там пытайтесь реализовать свою задумку. Если хотите прям как в VS Code, то из коробки подобный функционал есть в WinUI.

@EvgeniyZ Вы про WindowChrome ? Можно поподробней пожалуйста.
На счет WinUI, он пока не работает с Blazor, есть на гитхабе библиотека но там очень много НО, а в MAUI кастомизацию бара завезли только недавно в .NET 9...

А на кой черт вам Blazor, особенно в WPF? В MAUI еще могу понять, кроссплатформ и все такое, где разработчики ленятся разрабатывать софт под все платформы, из-за чего делают веб сайт и тупо открывают его через браузер на всех платформах, но вы пишете (судя по тому, что выбираете WPF) исключительно под Windows, а это значит, что вам не нужна кроссплатформенность. Зачем тогда в вашем десктоп приложении нужен целый браузер под капотом? Чтобы вы могли вывести веб "заголовок"? Ну это бред... С такими хотелками, вам тогда уж лучше в Electron (VS Code на нем кстати). "Подробней" - ссылка выше.

@EvgeniyZ Хочу использовать Blazor, потому что именно кроссплатформенность, и одна кодовая база для любой платформы, ни кто мне не мешает разместить потом код в MAUI и сделать билд под ios, или в вебе, к тому же css и html проще на много, именно для меня, и я смогу реализовать любые "хотелки" на blazor нежели на xaml, думаю сейчас выбор очевиден, в выборе фреймворка, и blazor мой фаворит, и он не ограничивает меня как xaml который ни как помереть не может.
Вы можете пояснить про хром пожалуйста ?  на счет электрона, я не силен в js, а Electron.NET на него походу забили = (

Советую тогда подтянуть свои знания, раз "не силен". "одна кодовая база для любой платформы" - это MAUI, из коробки вам все это дает, стоит познать его возможности, познать XAML, как с ним работать, как правильно писать приложения, тогда отпадет вообще желание делать "Франкенштейна". Повторю, вы сейчас пытаетесь сделать глупость, ибо вы жертвуете производительностью и ресурсами ваших клиентов в угоду мнимого удобства... Почему? А потому что вы туда пихаете WebView2 (по сути хром браузер), который выведет ваш сайт и вместо 50мб RAM вы потратите ну 300-500+++...

Короче, если хотите хорошее, качественное десктоп приложение, то изучите MAUI и не изобретайте велосипедов. WPF тут вообще не в тему, ибо вы не перенесете просто так один код из одного проекта в другой, даже используя "гибрид" приложение, лучше писать всю его базу на кроссплатформенных решениях, ну а в C# это MAUI. Если вы хотите всеж веб, то мой совет, изучите JS и другие WEB приблуды и пишите приложение на Electron. Не нравиться что он "заброшен", возьмите альтернативу, например, Tauri. "Пояснить про хром" - что именно? Давайте просто дам ответ.

@EvgeniyZ Вы меня не поняли, мне не нужно настраивать окно в WPF, там это делает легко, мне нужно обойти проверку нажатия левой кнопки мыши при вызове 'DragMove', вы сказали что это не нужно и достаточно вернуть "хром", можно вот тут по подробней.
если что я нажимаю на  элемент в браузере, и хочу что бы окно приложения передвигалось
а так как это не элемент интерфейса wpf то и аргумент передать я не могу, что бы пройти проверку.
'protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e); <---
this.DragMove();
}'

И по поводу blazor, разве Electron это не браузер ? то есть их браузер на хроме 110 версии не тормозит, а webview2 на последней версии тормозит ?

Хром - это стандартное поведение окна (перетаскивание, изменение размера, кнопки закрытия, и так далее), если вы переписываете окно, но хотите вернуть эти стандартные механизмы, то достаточно добавить хром обратно, как - я дал уже 2 ссылки выше... Другими словами, вам не нужно подписываться на события нажатия мыши, проверять там что-то, вам надо просто вернуть хром и он все вернет на свои места.

"Electron браузер" - я вам говорю не про то, что там браузер или нет, а про то, что тот-же MAUI имеет свои механизмы создания интерфейса, которые могут многое, заменять их "браузером", ну, бред... Зачем тогда вам условный MAUI, если вы пренебрегаете его возможностями..? Лучше уж тогда использовать то, что изначально заточено под веб. Это как, не знаю, купить Mac устройство ради того, чтобы установить на него Windows, да еще и попутно железо поменять для лучшей совместимости... Вот что-то такое вы делаете сейчас. В любом случае, на ваш вопрос невозможно сейчас дать один ответ, слишком общий.

Вот и получается вы меня не поняли от слова совсем, как я уже писал с кастомизацией в wpf у меня нету проблем, мне нужно не восстановить функциональность titlebar, а заменить его на web интерфейс, точней что бы интерфейс выступал в роли нового titlebar, и поэтому мне нужно найти обходной путь, но с возможностью восстановить остальные прелести хрома = )
На счет MAUI, я изучал 2 года назад xaml, он мне не понравился, а недавно, открыв WinUI 3 Gallery, и после того как демонстрационное приложение с кнопачками вылетает у меня через раз, я понял что мне там делать нечего.

@EvgeniyZ  По именно моему вопросу вы ничем помочь мне не сможете ?

"не поняли" - перечитайте мой первый комментарий, я вам изначально сказал, что вы делаете что-то не то. DragMove я указал там как пример ваших лишних действий, а не решением вашей задачи. Так с чего вы взяли, что я не понял вас? Может это вы не поняли меня? Ведь я вам уже кучу раз сказал, что все навороты по типу перетаскивания, дает хром, который просто надо вернуть окну. Вот что вам мешает создать стиль окну, где будет сетка с двумя Row, в первой помещаете "браузер" с вашим заголовком, во вторую оставшийся контент, также хром, которому задаете размер верхней части == высоте браузера.

"не понравился" - повторю, если вы не используете самые главные технологии конкретной платформы, значит эта платформа не для вас. Знаете HTML и хотите писать на нем, я уже сказал что лучше использовать. Повторю, вы сейчас покупаете Apple технику, говорите "фи, мне не нравиться Mac OS", ставите на нее Windows. Какой смысл этих действий, этих костылей, я не пойму... В любом случае, повторю, на ваш вопрос дать ответ невозможно, ибо вы сами не знаете что хотите, не знаете что выбрать. Вам нужна кроссплатформ, но вы берете WPF... Так что, голосую за закрытие вопроса, а вам советую его уточнить.
